# SwipeEvent on Android app

Tags: android

Am making an application to control SwipeEvent but is only working the validations left to right and right to left. Validations up-down and down-up are not working.
Sorry for the messages in Toast are in Portuguese. Basically:

```
(x1 <x2) - left to right / (x1> x2) - right to left / (y1 <y2) - up to down
(y1> y2) - down to up
```

> I Changed "getX () and getY ()" to "getRawX () and getRawY ()". The result remains the same. For example, if I do a swipe motion from left to direct the displayed Toast is "Swipe Left to Right (OK) and Swipe Top to Down (not ok).

Could someone please help me?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

float x1,x2;
float y1,y2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//onTouchEvent() é o metodo chamado quando o usuário realiza um evento de toque na tela
//Método que trata evento de toque como Swipe

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
    switch (touchevent.getAction())
    {
        //Ao usuário tocar na tela pela primeira vez, obtem as coordenadas x e y
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            //if para validar swipe da esquerda para direita
            if(x1<x2)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Esquerda para Direita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //if para validar swipe da direita para esquerda
            if(x1>x2)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Direita para Esquerda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //if para validar swipe de cima para baixo
            if(y1<y2)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Cima para Baixo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //if para validar swipe de baixo para cima
            if(y1>y2)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Baixo para Cima", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
        return false;

}
}
```

Comment: Don't we need to return `true` in above method?

Answer (score 0):

The motion event may return coordinates relative to the previous event.

To avoid this, use `touchevent.getRawX()`, and `touchevent.getRawY()` instead of `getX()` and `getY()`

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. Changed to "getX () and getY ()" to "getRawX () and getRawY ()". The result remains the same. For example, if I do a swipe motion from left to direct the displayed Toast is "Swipe Left to Right (OK) and Swipe Top to Down (not ok)." @Greg Ennis